# Managing multiple rows and columns returned from a SQLite database in iOS

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I am dealing with `sqlite` database in `iOS`. In my `sqlite` query, i am retrieving multiple columns and rows from the DB. The name of the columns are `"Username", "Task", "Period", "Date", "Status"`. All these fields are of type `"text"`. The query will retrieve all rows from the table corresponding to a specific `Username`.

I have no clue how to manage the data that is returned. I need some part of the data (only the Task and Date) to be shown in a table and the rest of the part (period and other related things) to be shown when one of the rows is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom NSObject subclass to house these custom properties. You can set one up like so:

```
@interface Employee

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* username;
...

@end
```

If you have tested your queries and they are fast even when you pull all those fields (including the ones you don't need at that point in time) then just store them in that class with the first query. Then when the row is accessed you can simply access whichever property you need. If things are getting slow and you don't need certain information at that time, then perform a subsequent query when that extra information is required.